# Error: class definition in method body and dynamic constant assignment PLAN_POLICIES = [

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to apply some of this code:

```
  class Guest

attr_accessor :custom0, :custom6, :custom7, :custom8

def initialize(args)
  args.each do |k,v|
    self.send("#{k}=",v)
  end
end

end

PLAN_POLICIES = [
{number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 64},
{number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 53},
{number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 63},
{number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 52},
{number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 62},
{number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 51},
{number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 61},
{number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 50},
]


def plan_id
return PLAN_POLICIES.find do |pp|
  pp[:number_of_guests] == number_of_guests && pp[:type_of_guest] == type_of_guest
end[:plan_id]    
end

 def number_of_guests
@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i
end

def type_of_guest
return "MP" if @guest.custom0 == "MP"
return "MP PLATINO" if @guest.custom8 == "MP PLATINO"
end


@usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(plan_id)
```

But I got this error:
**"class definition in method body"**

**"dynamic constant assignment
  PLAN_POLICIES = ["**

Here is the full code of this: [Full Code Here](https://mega.nz/#!0UAFnBTL!i0UOomz8KVAyMNov0H8ANgSYI3uOR-nLyRWTSgMeCwg)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Besth Whises!

Comment: Thanks for posting this as a new question. I'm replying now. Be right with you... Oh. And can you please add to your question the `class` where you put the code I recommended? (Nevermind, I got it.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First of all, `constant` declarations (by convention, in all caps) need to go just below your class declaration (never inside a method definition, as you had), like this:

```
  class Portal::RoseController < PortalController

    PLAN_POLICIES = [
      {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 64},
      {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 53},
      {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 63},
      {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 52},
      {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 62},
      {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 51},
      {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 61},
      {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 50},
    ]
    ...
  end
```

And, you're going to want to finish that list out, because it's incomplete.

Then, you have this:

```
  def pms_guest_purchase
    super
    # if there is a free plan match, then we want to pick the most appropriate
    # plan and automatically purchase it.  For now, we will just select the one
    # most appropriate plan.

    class Guest

      attr_accessor :custom0, :custom6, :custom7, :custom8

      def initialize(args)
        args.each do |k,v|
          self.send("#{k}=",v)
        end
      end

    end
    ...
  end
```

But, like I said in my other post, `Guest` was just for the example. So, get rid of that entirely.

With that gone, you now have this:

```
  def pms_guest_purchase
    super
    # if there is a free plan match, then we want to pick the most appropriate
    # plan and automatically purchase it.  For now, we will just select the one
    # most appropriate plan.


    def plan_id
      return PLAN_POLICIES.find do |pp|
        pp[:number_of_guests] == number_of_guests && pp[:type_of_guest] == type_of_guest
      end[:plan_id]    
    end

    def number_of_guests
      @guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i
    end

    def type_of_guest
      return "MP" if @guest.custom0 == "MP"
      return "MP PLATINO" if @guest.custom8 == "MP PLATINO"
    end

    ...
  end
```

But you *never* declare methods inside methods like that. So, move them out, like this:

```
  def plan_id
    return PLAN_POLICIES.find do |pp|
      pp[:number_of_guests] == number_of_guests && pp[:type_of_guest] == type_of_guest
    end[:plan_id]    
  end

  def number_of_guests
    @guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i
  end

  def type_of_guest
    return "MP" if @guest.custom0 == "MP"
    return "MP PLATINO" if @guest.custom8 == "MP PLATINO"
  end

  def pms_guest_purchase
    super
    # if there is a free plan match, then we want to pick the most appropriate
    # plan and automatically purchase it.  For now, we will just select the one
    # most appropriate plan.

    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(plan_id)

    if @guest 
      ...
    end

  end
```

See how you have that `if @guest` statement? Move `@usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(plan_id)` inside there. Because `type_of_guest` and `number_of_guests` will fail if there's no `@guest`. And, if this was my code, I'd make those helper methods `private`. So, you end up with this:

```
  class Portal::RoseController < PortalController

      PLAN_POLICIES = [
        {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 64},
        {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 53},
        {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 63},
        {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 52},
        {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 62},
        {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 51},
        {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 61},
        {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 50},
      ]

    ...


    def pms_guest_purchase
      super
      # if there is a free plan match, then we want to pick the most appropriate
      # plan and automatically purchase it.  For now, we will just select the one
      # most appropriate plan.

      if @guest 
        @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(plan_id)
        ...
      end

    end

    ...

  private

    def plan_id
      return PLAN_POLICIES.find do |pp|
        pp[:number_of_guests] == number_of_guests && pp[:type_of_guest] == type_of_guest
      end[:plan_id]    
    end

    def number_of_guests
      @guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i
    end

    def type_of_guest
      return "MP" if @guest.custom0 == "MP"
      return "MP PLATINO" if @guest.custom8 == "MP PLATINO"
    end

  end
```

Also, I don't how much control or influence you have over this code base, but that `rose_controller` is WAAAAY too fat. A whole bunch of that stuff should be moved into plain old ruby objects. (We can do a separate Q&A on that if you like.)

FWIW.

Good luck and let me know if you have problems.